# Salesforce lead tracking with contact forms plugins

Tags: customization, contact, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 on my website and would like to integrate Salesforce lead tracking with it.

I was able to add a hidden field with my oid as suggested [on this site](http://www.e-nor.com/blog/index.php/web-analytics/avoid-data-dispersion-with-salesforce-and-google-adwords-integration/)

But when I submit the contact form after adding this, it just gets stuck and never actually returns. As soon as I remove the hidden field, it starts working fine.

Has anyone been able to integrate the lead tracking system with Wordpress Contact Form plugins?

I also tried using cform with the instructions [provided here](http://www.jackreichert.com/2010/08/howto-salesforce-multiple-web-to-lead-forms-wordpress/). But this gives a warning that fopen failed. I assume thats because fopen does not allow write operations with HTTP wrappers. Not sure how the author managed to get it working!

Would appreciate any help on this! I do not want to use the salesforce Web-to-lead form. Thanks.

Comment: Check out this tutorial: https://gaconnector.com/blog/salesforce-contact-form-7-free-10-minute-integration-guide/
And this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18p6TOoOORY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the [Gravity Forms plugin](http://www.gravityforms.com/) and its post form-submission hook to fire off a server-side web2lead curl request in wordpress before now. Wasn't too difficult.

Essentially your web2lead form submission is purely server-side so the regular gravity forms entry logging (including IP etc...) just carries on working. You get your data in both WP and SF.

Comment: Also now has a Salesforce plugin  which supports web-to-lead http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravity-forms-salesforce/

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tutorial about this on my blog:
[how to integrate salesforce in contact form 7](http://www.alexhager.at/how-to-integrate-salesforce-in-contact-form-7/)

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you don't want to use S/F's web to lead?  I had a client that wanted to the same, and salesforce's web to lead form worked.  It works best though if you paste the code directly into the template.  And their web to lead code provides built in js validation, so you don't really have to do much other than style it.

Comment: Quite some reasons I dont want to use it - I want the IP addr from which the request was sent. Using the other plugins I can send an email with the information whereas with the web-to-lead plugin it will only be updated in Sforce. There is no spam-protection with the SF form/plugin

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of benefits of **not** using the standard Web to Lead. Spam issues, validation, requiring certain fields, and visitor tracking to name a few.

One of the above entries links to Alex Hager's site which has an excellent guide, I used that as the basis for my own tweaked instructions (90% copied from Alex's) which also include info on how to use this with Custom Fields.

http://daddyanalytics.com/integrating-contact-form-7-and-salesforce/

Or, if you want something simple without programming but that has the bells and whistles of Contact Form 7, try the Wordpress to Lead plugin,

http://wordpress.org/plugins/salesforce-wordpress-to-lead/